Why does `yshift` crash the compilation when I switch the intersection order
Consider this MWE
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
% \documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone} % for Beamer

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{
  ar/.style={-latex,shorten >=-1pt, shorten <=-1pt},
  mynode/.style={draw, thick, shape=rectangle, minimum size=12pt, align=center, anchor=west, rounded corners=4pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, thick, shape=circle, minimum size=1pt, anchor=west, inner sep=5pt, name=mixer-x] at (0,0) {};
    \draw (mixer-x.north west) -- (mixer-x.south east);
    \draw (mixer-x.north east) -- (mixer-x.south west);

    \node[draw, thick, shape=circle, minimum size=1pt, anchor=west, inner sep=5pt, name=mixer-y] at (50pt, 0) {};
    \draw (mixer-y.north west) -- (mixer-y.south east);
    \draw (mixer-y.north east) -- (mixer-y.south west);

    \node[mynode] at (150pt, 50pt) (viterbi) {Viterbi\\algorithm};

    \draw[ar] (mixer-y.east) -- ([yshift=5pt]viterbi.west -| mixer-y.east);
    % \draw[ar] (mixer-y.east) -- (mixer-y.east |- [yshift=5pt]viterbi.west); % WHAT IS THE ERROR???
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

When I simply change ([yshift=5pt]viterbi.west -| mixer-y.east) by (mixer-y.east |- [yshift=5pt]viterbi.west), it prompts
Package pgf: No shape named `[yshift=5pt]viterbi' is known.LaTeX

It should work perfectly fine, but for some reason [yshift=5pt] is preventing it from working properly. If you remove and leave it as (mixer-y.east |- viterbi.west), it works. Why?

This is probably due to how TikZ parses the syntax. But such a syntax does not make any sense to me anyways, since ([yshift=5pt]viterbi.west -| mixer-y.east) is the coordinate at the vertical part of (viterbi.west) and at the horizontal part of (mixer-y.east) and this shifted by 5pt vertically. Thus, (viterbi.west -| [yshift=5pt]mixer-y.east) (if it was allowed) would mean that you get the the coordinate at the vertical part of (viterbi.west) and at the horizontal part of (mixer-y.east) shifted vertically by 5pt, which however would be the same as if it was not shifted.

Sorry, my comment is wrong. You want to have (viterbi.west |- [yshift=5pt]mixer-y.east). But this would be the very same as ([yshift=5pt]viterbi.west |- mixer-y.east) if I am not mistaken.

Such a syntax is not supported. But it does not really make sense to me anyways: You try to get (mixer-y.east |- [yshift=5pt]viterbi.west) working, but which coordinate would that be? It would be the same as ([yshift=5pt]mixer-y.east |- viterbi.west).
Let us analyze how the syntax using the orthogonal operator works first:
(A |- B) is the coordinate at the horizontal position of (A) and the vertical position of (B).
If you add an option with yshift to this, you will vertically shift this coordinate by the relevant value. For example, ([yshift=5pt]A |- B) will shift the coordinate 5pt vertically.
Now, you try something like (A |- [yshift=5pt]B). If such syntax would be supported, it should probably be the coordinate at the horizontal position of (A) and the vertical position of ([yshift=5pt]B).
But this is exactly the same coordinate which you get with ([yshift=5pt]A |- B) since it does not matter whether you shift vertically before or after getting the coordinated via the orthogonal operator. Thus, ([yshift=5pt]A |- B) and ([yshift=5pt]B -| A) are the exact same coordinate.
In short, the answer is just: The TikZ parser does not support such a syntax. Options in square brackets can only come as first part after the opening parenthesis of a coordinate if I am not mistaken. As for why it does not support such a syntax, you need to ask the package creators, but it is probably because the parser can't cover too many variants of the syntax. In the end, you can just put the yshift option in front which results in the same coordinate anyways, so there is no need for such a syntax in my opinion.

I hope this answer is at least a bit understandable :D

Yes, they are the same coordinate but the reason it doesn't work is ridiculous. That is why LaTeX s*cks and Typst will replace it (crossed fingers). Thank you for your explanation.

@RubemPacelli While it might be true that TeX is sometimes not very straightforward, I don’t think that your accusations hold here since it is TikZ that has a special syntax. It is just the way the TikZ parser works. =)

Well, yes, the options can only come right after the ( but TikZ throws both of the coordinates in this implicit |-/-| syntax in the same parser again, but interestingly at a point after options would have been scanned. Fixing this doesn't seem to have a negative effect but who knows …
